# Installing ROS on Nexus 4

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently changes the os on my nexus 4 to Ubuntu touch and i tried installing ROS the traditional way onto the device. But everytime i try to install i keep getting errors saying that the package was not found or cannot be installed. I havent found much documentation on this topic. How would i be able to install ROS on the device ?. I need to install it on my robot to control the bot and carry out all the processing.

Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182656/installing-ros-on-nexus-4/) by [raghu.s1211](https://answers.ros.org/users/11086/raghu.s1211/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TillScout](https://answers.ros.org/users/686/tillscout/) on 2014-07-12**:
Have you been successful already? I am curious about the performance of ROS on Ubuntu Touch devices.

**Comment by [pendragon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32929/pendragon/) on 2019-03-26**:
Anybody figured out a way to do this yet? I got a project coming up and we need to use a portable device capable of running ROS.

Any and all suggestions are welcomed. Thanks

**Comment by [dpills](https://answers.ros.org/users/113822/dpills/) on 2022-08-14**:
Hi any one who has succeeded to run ROS on Ubuntu touch or on any of the newest version OTA22/23 UBports on any mobile devices ?

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure but I think that packages for Ubuntu touch are different from the packages for desktop computers having the standard Ubuntu.
From this page it looks like ros precompiled packages are indeed only available for Desktop Ubuntu

> http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/

If this is the case you should install ROS by your own by compiling from the source code. Here is how to do it

> http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raghu.s1211](https://answers.ros.org/users/11086/raghu.s1211/) on 2014-07-03**:
can i install groovy instead of hydro using the source code ?

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-07-03**:
check this link http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Source

**Comment by [raghu.s1211](https://answers.ros.org/users/11086/raghu.s1211/) on 2014-07-07**:
Thank you very much. Ill try it and follow up.

**Comment by [stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19765/stefan/) on 2014-08-19**:
any news from ros on ubuntu touch?